# How do I search through images in the directory and save them into another folder?

Tags: python, image

Assume that there is a folder that has 10,000 images in it.

I have a  `abc.text` file that has 400 lines in it, each line contains one image name in it, a total of 400 images.

These images are located in that image folder.

`text file` is like :

```
UIO 15 09:5522:106 XOP UIO[24371]: 1525-522-15220 1555:068524:167855 INFO      Filename: 1852585.jpeg
UIO 15 52522:2505:106 XOP UIO[52585]: 1525-522-152920 1555:068524:167855 INFO      Filename: 1052520.jpeg
```

I want to read all the images from that text file, find them in that image folder and save them with the same name into a new directory.

I am wondering if I can automate this? Is there anyways to do it quickly?

Comment: Are you on Windows, or something Linux-like?

Comment: I use ubuntu system

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
cat /path_to_text_file.txt | awk '{print $10}' | xargs -i cp /path_to_image_folder/{} /path_to_dest_dir
```

Comment: Let's hope the filename is always exactly the 10th field, and that there are no spaces in it.

Comment: it says "cp: target '1852585.jpeg' is not a directory", what does it mean exactly?

Comment: It means the `xargs` command has the parameters wrong. I would recommend working on a **copy** of your files until you get a decent, tested, reliable answer.

Comment: you must go to the image folder, and give the text file as absolute path of it. if you have any other question you can post you directory layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os,shutil
images_list=glob.glob(PATH/OF/IMAGES/*.jpg)
file=open(PATH.txt,"r").read().split(/n)

for image_name in file:
    if image_name in images_list:
        shutils.copyfile(image_name,"NEWFOLDER/"+image_name)
```

Comment: can you please give a runnable answer? how do I save those images with their original names?

Comment: shutils.copyfile(image_name,"NEWFOLDER/"+image_name)